# FabricJS Polygon object is over-offset

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on an interface that is comprised of multiple objects. I've trying to handle the scenario where the canvas/interface get resized. The offsets are all properly addressed, but there are two stubborn objects that refuse to offset/render correctly (Figure 1). Prior to resizing the interface, all the objects are correctly positioned (Figure 2).

The two objects in question are both of type polygon, whereas the rest are anything but. This makes me suspect that perhaps polygons require some additional step.

I have checked all the offsets and points coords and all the values are correctly assigned, yet it is still over-offsetting and when selected it get cut off.

There are thousands of lines of code where these objects are handled, thus impossible to share it all.
Nevertheless, based on the description and screenshots is there anything obvious that stands out?

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a clipping issue. Looks like you need to recalculate the position of the CanvasRenderingContext using its translate method. I can share my clipping function with you that considers all these factors and that I was currently working on. I use this clipping function only on the images, but I assume it should work in a similar way on the polygons too, on its http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Polygon.html#clipTo method.

```
 export class ObjectClippingService {
    private _zoomRateService: X.ZoomRateService
    private _window: any

    constructor(zoomRateService: X.ZoomRateService, window: ng.IWindowService) {
        this._zoomRateService = zoomRateService
        this._window = window
    }

    public clipping(ctx, target, isOriginalSize?: boolean) {
        var rectObj
        var left
        var top
        var angle
        var zoomRate = this._zoomRateService.dynamicZoomRate

        if (!!isOriginalSize) {
            zoomRate = 1
        }

        ctx.save()
        ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)

        if (this.isGroupImageFrame(target)) {
            rectObj = target.getObjects('rect')[0]
            left = (target.left + rectObj.left + target.width * target.scaleX / 2) * zoomRate
            top = (target.top + rectObj.top + target.height * target.scaleY / 2) * zoomRate
        } else {
            left = target.left * zoomRate
            top = target.top * zoomRate
        }

        angle = target.angle * Math.PI / 180
        console.log('Rotating the clipping by: ' + angle)
        ctx.translate(left, top)
        ctx.rotate(angle)

        this.clipTheImage(target, ctx, zoomRate)
        ctx.restore()
    }

    private isGroupImageFrame(target): boolean {
        return target.fixedItem === 'image' && target.type === 'group' && !target.isFrame && target.newGroupType !== 'circle'
    }

    private rectFrame(target, ctx, zoomRate) {
        var rectObj = !!this.isGroupImageFrame(target) ? target.getObjects("rect")[0] : target

        const clippingRectWidth = rectObj.width * zoomRate * rectObj.scaleX
        const clippingRectHeight = rectObj.height * zoomRate * rectObj.scaleY

        ctx.rect(0, 0, clippingRectWidth, clippingRectHeight)
    }

    private circleFrame(target, ctx, zoomRate) {
        var width = target.width * zoomRate * target.scaleX / 2

        ctx.arc(width, width, width, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    }

    private clipTheImage(target, ctx, zoomRate) {
        if (target.newGroupType == 'rect') this.rectFrame(target, ctx, zoomRate)
        if (target.newGroupType === 'circle') this.circleFrame(target, ctx, zoomRate)
    }
}
```

I call the service inside the clipTo method:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(src, function (img: any) {
    img.set({
        ...,
        clipTo: (ctx) => {
            return X._objectClippingService.clipping(ctx, customTarget);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: According to the documentation clipTo has been deprecated since 2.0.0 and I'm on 2.3.3, but I'll give it a try and see what comes out of it. Thanks for the response.